# How do I return a boolean value for a form's "onsubmit" attribute depending on the success or error of an ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

If my form is defined as follows:

```
    <form action="myAction" method="post" id="input" target="_parent" onsubmit="doThis();">
```

and doThis() is part of the following script:

```
var result = false;

function doThis() {
    var myUrl = 'http://somewebsite.com/SomeWebservice/Webservice?args1=AAA&callback=?';

    var status = false;
    $.ajax({
        url : myUrl,
        type : 'get',
        dataType : 'jsonp',
        success : function(res) {
            onSuccess(res);
        },
        error : function(e, msg, error) {
            onError(e, msg, error);
        }
    });

    return result;
}

function onError(e, msg, error) {
    // do stuff if error

    result = false;
}

function onSuccess(res) {
    // do stuff if successful

    result = true;
}
```

What I'm expecting is that if the ajax call is successful, onSuccess will set result to true, then doThis will return true and the form will submit. However, this does not happen. In fact, nothing happens.

My suspicion is that since the ajax call is asynchronous, doThis already returns a value (false) before the ajax transaction completes, so the return is always false. If that's the case, how do I modify my code so that it returns true or false depending on whether the ajax call is successful or not?

I think I can set async to false, but I keep on reading that callbacks are a better way to code than doing "async : false" --- so I was wondering what the best solution for this is.

**EDIT:**

I've put the following alerts in the onError and onSuccess functions:

```
function onError(e, msg, error) {
    alert(e+" - "+msg+" - "+error);
    result = false;
}

function onSuccess(res) {
    alert("success");
    result = true;
}
```

And running my code confirms that the logic passes through onSuccess.

Answer (score 0):

Success is an AJAX event which is trigged after the AJAX completes http://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/ . So, what you are expecting is correct. Try adding some alerts to your code to see what each function is returning. like :

```html
  function onSuccess(res) {
// do stuff if successful
alert('Ajax success');
result = true;
}
```

Comment: I updated the OP for info regarding alerts. The alerts confirm that the code indeed passes through onSuccess(). But the form still does nothing and does not submit.

Comment: Did you mean that its not going to myAction?

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove 'onsubmit' property.

```html
<form action="myAction" method="post" id="input" target="_parent">
```

2. Instead use 'onclick' property. let's say your form is submitted by button or html element. 
   call $('.YourFormSubmitElement').onclick('doThis'). Note that if your has multiple form submission elements use class selector else if it is one use id selector.

   Use the below function to submit the form.

```js
  function doThis() {
        var myUrl = 'http://somewebsite.com/SomeWebservice/Webservice?args1=AAA&callback=?';
    
        $.ajax({
            url : myUrl,
            type : 'get',
            dataType : 'jsonp',
            success : function(res) {
                 $('#input').submit();
            }
        });
    }
```

I think this should fix your problem.

Comment: Unfortunately when I do this, the submission loops because I'm already calling doThis() in the onsubmit attribute on the form... so doThis() ends up being called recursively.

Comment: @heisenbergman Hmm. Haste makes waste. I can see your point. In this case setting 'async: false' only solve your problem as you described in your question since the calls has to be sequential .i.e ajax call has to be made only when form submission is initiated by end user and form submission has to be done only when ajax call is succeeded

Comment: Unfortunately... I just learned today that jsonp transactions are apparently async by nature. You can't set jsonp to transact synchronously :(

Comment: @heisenbergman,  Updated as the answer with new suggestion. Since most of html elements are supported with onclick property, this should solve your problem i guess

Answer (score 0):

r you sure that ajax request return success and go to function onSuccess(res) ?
you should add alert to know where the code goes. may be its goes to error : function(e, msg, error). alert what  error msg saying?

Comment: I updated the OP for info regarding alerts. The alerts confirm that the code indeed passes through onSuccess().

Comment: try re assign value of result :
result = onSuccess(res);

Comment: won't this just call onSuccess, which would automatically set result to true regardless if the ajax is successful or not?

Comment: if ajax is successfull the resust was set equals true. alert the result after call onSuccess() to know exactly what result is and maybeyou should return result after call onSuccess()

Comment: java script is running step by step so you should be return result after assign value in onSuccess()

Comment: actually, that's the problem... the ajax-jsonp call is asynchronous... it doesn't run step-by-step...

Comment: asyn false that mean you have many action want to run at the same time. e.g : you have two ajax action and asyn false allow it run together. if you have only 1 ajax request you could add asyn true.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest if possible you can go for [Jquery Form Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/). Instead of invoking an jquery ajax call 
you can invoke `ajaxForm` or `ajaxSubmit`functions provided by that plugin. You can use these two functions just like an ajax call and it also supports `success` or error `callback` functions

Sample usage

```
$('#input').ajaxForm({
    url:        myUrl , 
    success : function(response) {
       // handle success
    },
    error : function() {
       // handle error
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I can't utilize plugins just like that. If there were a way to make the webpage behave the way I want without plugins, that would be appreciated.